# Why does updateChildValues overwrites instead of updating data in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a node in Firebase Database using `.updateChildValues` method, but it overwrites the whole node instead of updating it with the new values. Does anyone why this happens?

```
func writeToDB() {
   let path = "FeesCleaner/\(self.fromUidString.text!)"
    let childUpdates = [path:  self.feesCleaner_Object] as [String : Any]
        self.dbRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, response) in
        })
 }

//self.feesCleaner_Object is shown below in JSON format.

"FeesCleaner" : {
  "05MSPgkP1ddhFqXDRjIB4npGEPV2" : {
    "BackgroundCheck" : {
      "FeeAmount" : "30",
      "FeeStatus" : "false",
      "TimeStampProfileCreated" : "2992939382"
   },
    "OutstandingFees" : {
      "BalanceCarriedForwardAmount" : "0.0",
      "PreviousBalanceCarriedForward" : "0.0",
      "TimeStampFeesCarriedForward" : "1520287823"
   },
   "TimeStampFeesSaved" : {
     "1520287823" : {
       "BalanceCarriedForwardAmount" : "0.0",
       "PayPeriodTimeStampStartDate" : "1510531260",
       "PaymentRef" : "354576819",
       "PreviousBalanceCarriedForward" : "0.0",
       "TimeStampDisbursedPayment" : "1520287823",
       "TotalAmountDebtToCleaner" : "0.0",
       "TotalAmountFeesCurrentPayPeriod" : "0.0",
       "TotalAmountPaidToCleanerForAllBookings" : "0.0",
       "TotalAmountProfitToCleanerForAllBookings" : "0.0"
     }
   }
  }
},
```

Comment: Which values are you trying to update?  It looks like you are passing the entire self.feesCleaner_Object object in your `.updateChildValues` command.

Comment: @Parrett Apps  I am trying to update the whole object. When `updateChildValues` is called I expect it to update the key values under `BackgroundCheck` and `OutstandingFees`. In addition I expect it to add new child to `TimeStampFeesSaved` which would look like: TimeStampFeesSaved/timeStampNow: { json obj here as shown above}. The purpose of `TimeStampFeesSaved ` is to record every payment made based on the time stamp when it was made. Later on I could load the payments in the UI based on TimeStampFeesSaved/timeStamp.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your issue entirely, but are you trying to update BackgroundCheck and OutstandingFees, but add a new entry under TimeStampFeesSaved without overwriting previous TimeStampFeesSaved nodes?  If so, you can use `.updateChildValues` to update the BackgroundCheck and OutstandingFees and then use `.setValue` to write a new entry under TimeStampFeesSaved.

Comment: @ParrettApps I will do it, but this requires 2 requests to Firebase server and more code to write, I was trying to do everything in one go.  I don't understand why `.updateChildValues` acts as `.setValue` in my particular case. It looks like `.updateChildValues` is not actually updating all the time, so it does not respect CRUD convention. I would appreciate if you could give me more insight into this matter.

Comment: Given a single key path, updateChildValues only updates data at the first child level, and any data passed in beyond the first child level is a treated as a setValue operation. Multi-path behavior allows longer paths to be used without overwriting data. Take a look at the example and related documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-update

Comment: @ParrettApps . If you put it into an answer, I will set it as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a single key path, updateChildValues only updates data at the first child level, and any data passed in beyond the first child level is a treated as a setValue operation. Multi-path behavior allows longer paths to be used without overwriting data. Take a look at the example and related documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-update

Comment: Do you know by any chance the reason why the Firebase engineers decided on that behaviour? namely .updateChildValues to act as setValue? It looks very misleading.

Comment: I really don't know, but I suspect it has to do with speed somehow.  At least they documented the behavior, even if it was buried a little.